# Calling an overriden static method from parent

Tags: php, inheritance, visibility

I have two classes. A child and a parent. The parent is calling a static method from the child (that's an overriden static parent method in the child class) and I get a general server error.
When I remove the relation ('extends' part), all is fine and get no errors. No idea why. Can't you override static methods? Looked for answers but can't seem to find them.

```
Class Fase {

  public static function getbyId($id) {
   //some stuff
      }
  public function getsomefaseitem($fase_item_id) {
     FaseItem::getbyid($fase_item_id);
    }

}

Class FaseItem extends Fase {

  public static function getbyId($id) {

      }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand OOP, parent-classes aren't supposed to call their child-classes...

Comment: "A general server error" is not useful. Look at the error log and provide some actual detail.

Comment: I got the following error: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: @Martijn: That's just the useless notice your browser throws up. Go into your server error log to find out the _actual_ PHP error.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'Kal . Thanks, I got it now. I looked into the php error log and the error was caused by setting 'private' __construct() in FaseItem.

Comment: @Martijn: This means that you didn't _test_ the sample code you gave us, thereby wasting everybody's time. Please _test_ when you write questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[It works for me.](http://www.ideone.com/PHexF)

---

This seems weird, though. The base should have no knowledge of the derived.

Perhaps use `static::` instead and rely on overriding static member functions — or "late static binding". You'll need PHP 5.3 for this.

```
<?php
class Fase {
   public static function getbyId($id) {
      echo "Fase::getbyId\n";
   }

   public function getsomefaseitem($fase_item_id) {
      static::getbyid($fase_item_id); // <---
   }
}

class FaseItem extends Fase {

   public static function getbyId($id) {
     echo "FaseItem::getbyId\n";
   }
}


$f = new Fase();
$f->getsomefaseitem(0);
?>
```

Comment: How to make sure if `getbyId` method do exits in the child class?